# Deployment template parse failed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Tags: mysql, deployment, azure-rm-template, azureportal

While i am trying to deploy a azure template through azure portal i am getting validation error as `

```html
{
  "telemetryId": "8a5ab567-31cf-4eb4-832b-4f6ce5d98986",
  "bladeInstanceId": "Blade_15b8aeb39a5249f788c6d40029a3b77b_6_0",
  "galleryItemId": "MyGalleryItem",
  "createBlade": "DeployToAzure",
  "code": "InvalidTemplate",
  "message": "Deployment template parse failed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'."
}
```

How to debug the error.
Please help in this regard.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the template replacing any sensitive info with fake info. Without seeing the template there is no way to help.

Comment: Hi Asif TMd, you might see this error when the URL you are using includes extra markup. Instead try using the raw URL. To add more context, we generally see such error when there is something in your template which is not parsed correctly by the engine. Hope this helps! And yeah, I second whatever Brian mentioned i.e., please mask sensitive information and provide complete template so that it helps to diagnose the issue in a better way.

Comment: Thanks Brian and KrishnaG, I will check with the url and also will post you the masked content